# SQL developer create materialized views

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, materialized-views

I want to create a materialized view with oracle SQL developer
It should refresh hourly

So i do this:

[image]

If it understand correctly, by setting "SPECIFY" as "When", and by setting 13:00:00 as "Start on" and 14:00:00 as "Next", the MV should refresh itself hourly

But it doesn't work...

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: May be the permissions on the user, or job queue process setup that you are using to create the MView. See this: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4043198500346862004

Comment: Can't see the image. What doesnt work exactly? The CREATE MV or its refresh? Can you show the generated statements?

Answer (score 0):

Michael Broughton was rigth, i had some permissions problems
By granting ALTER ANY MATERIALIZED VIEW to USER i resolved the problem

Thank you